# Angular bootstrap datepicker(uib-datepicker) not apply to new added elements

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker, uib

I have a filed with [uib-datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup) that added to DOM with `jQuery` after page load.
Now when I focus to field, **datepicker** not shown!

**create and append date picker field**

```
var dateInput = 
   $compile("<input type='text' class='date-filter' 
   ng-model='dateFilter' 
   uib-datepicker-popup='yyyy-MM-dd' 
   is-open='datePicker[1]' 
   ng-focus='openDatePicker($event, 1)'>")($scope);

   $('#wapper').append(dateInput);
```

**open datepicker**

```
$scope.datePicker = [];
$scope.openDatePicker = function ($event, datePickerIndex) {
   $event.preventDefault();
   $event.stopPropagation();
   $scope.datePicker[datePickerIndex] = true;
};
```

It can be said: `uib-datepicker` not apply to filed at all!

What's the problem?